# Recursive Methods in Collections

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, implementation

I'm trying to learn and have a question about Recursive Methods in Collections I read here that:

"When implementing collection classes with recursive methods, we typically must write a pair of methods for each operation.
The first method is the public one specified in the interface. It can be written iteratively or recursively. It is written iteratively, it simply calls ...
The second method, which is a private static one that does all the work.

For example, suppose that we are implementing a generic priority queue (LN stores value as an Object) via a linked list, using a front instance variable and a priorityComparator instance variables. We would implement the add method in this class with the following pair of methods."

the QUOTED code is:

```
public void add (Object o)
  {front = add(front,o);}

  private static LN add (LN l, Object o)
  {
    if (l == null || priorityComparator.compare(l.value,o) < 0)
      return new LN(value,l);
    else {
      l.next = add(l.next, o);
      return l;
    }
  }
```

**The source of the above informations and code is here -> [link](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/15-200/lectures/llrecursion/lecture.html#Collection)**

**sadly enough I found just one source :(**

**QUESTION1:** I would like to know what benefit can this way of writing method brings to the implementation of a certain collection?

so per example, I wrote my implemented LinkedList methods like this:

```
//insertion....
public void insert(E data) {
    first = insertEnd(first, data);
    last = getLast();
    //length++;
}

private static <E> Node insert(Node head, E data) {
    if (head == null) {
        return new Node(data);
    } else {
        head.setNext(insert(head.getNext(), data));
    }

    return head;
}

public void printList() {
    printList(first);
    System.out.println();
}

private static void printList(Node head) {
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println("null");
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(head.getData() + "->");
    printList(head.getNext());
}

public int size() {
    return size(first);
}

private static int size(Node head) {
    if (head == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + size(head.getNext());
    }
}

public boolean contains(E data) {
    return contains(first, data);
}

public static <E> boolean contains(Node head, E data) {
    if (head == null || data == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (head.getData().equals(data)) {
        return true;
    }
    return contains(head.getNext(), data);
}
 //count occurrences of certain value
public int countIf(E t) {
    return countIf(first, t);
}

private static <E> int countIf(Node head, E t) {
    if (head == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (head.getData().equals(t)) {
        return 1 + countIf(head.getNext(), t);
    }

    return countIf(head.getNext(), t);
}

//TODO: WHY IM GETTING HERE AN OVERRIDE REQUEST FROM THE COMPILER??
public ListNode<E> clone() {
    first = clone(first);
    ListNode<E> copy = new ListNode<>(first);
    return copy;
}

private static Node clone(Node head) {
    if (head == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Node temp = new Node(head.getData());
    temp.setNext(clone(head.getNext()));

    return temp;
}

public ListNode<E> invert() {
    first = invert(first);
    ListNode<E> inverted = new ListNode<>(first);
    return inverted;
}

private static Node invert(Node head) {

    if (head.getNext() == null) {
        return head;
    }

    Node newHead = invert(head.getNext());

    head.getNext().setNext(head);//head.next.next=node;
    head.setNext(null);//gead.next=null;

    return newHead;
}
```

**Question2**is what is my following primitive idea about this topic right?
so as a beginner I would try to share my point of view about the potential benefit of this way and please try to correct me if I'm mistaken and if I missed something please point it out!

- first, in case of an `assertion` , `contains()` and `countIf()`, this might be helpful because in main the user wouldn't have to put the head of the list as a parameter.
  and because each method would be called like this `list1.method()` thus each list would have another `head node`.
- second, in case of `inverting` and `cloning`, where I have to return ListNode instead of `Node` i can understand that the creation of the list has to be in the `invert()` or `clone()` methods.

**sadly enough I couldn't find enough info online pls feel free to provide your favorite references and feel free to write your own explanation about this.**

have a nice one. :)

Comment: If this is two questions, then it should be two questions. But you seem to be asking for references/resources, which is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you want a useful answer, you will have to narrow your question down to one specific thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **QUESTION:** What benefit can this way of writing method bring to the implementation of a certain collection?

*Benefit:* It works. It's **doable**.

What's the alternative? One method? Which of the two would that be?

- `void insert(E data)`? Then how would the recursion work?
- `Node insert(Node head, E data)`? Where would caller get the `head` value? What would caller do with the return value?

Take another look at all your method pairs. Do you see a pattern? Like, all the private methods have a `Node` parameter. None of the public methods do.

Comment: so what exactly is the alternative that you are suggesting, what shall I change?  I didn't quite get what you mean, sir ?!

Comment: I had to do double methods because it's homework and I cant use iterative approaches.

Comment: @studentaccount4 I'm pointing out to you that you *have to* use two methods, because any attempt to use only one method wouldn't work for a recursive implementation.